# Change multiple checkboxes to radiobuttons

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have about 50 checkboxes in a group box.  I need to change them to radiobuttons... is there a way to do this *safely* and in bulk?

Comment: Dynamically (e.g. when a user clicks something) or just in writing code?

Comment: It sounds like you should tag a language.

Comment: Winforms? asp.net? WPF? silverlight? metro? console application?? please specify, as chances are there is a good way to do that, but that depends on the technology being used.

Comment: Changing to radiobuttons isn't just as simple because you need to create the hierarchy. Selecting one usually results in unselecting others, and this logic needs to be added to the software.

Comment: gl3829: please post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to change mark-up e.g. changing this:

```
<input type="radio" id="rad1" name="myGroup" value="1" />Button 1<br/>
<input type="radio" id="rad2" name="myGroup" value="2"/>Button 2<br/>
```

to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1"/>Checkbox 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="2"/>Checkbox 2
```

then running Find and Replace a couple of times should do what you need. At minimum you will need to change the type property and remove the name property.

However, if you are working with ASP.NET server controls or if you have client-side JavaScript running then, as others have written, you may need to revisit your code to ensure your logic is still consistent when the controls have changed.